# Need to make formula across a range act on only rows with a given value in row u

Tags: vba, excel

Need the following code to only act on rows where the value in column u is greater than 1.

```
Sub formulae_wfc()
    Range("v4:v200").Formula = "=T4*U4*0.01"
    Range("x4:x200").Formula = "=T4-V4"
    Range("aj4:aj200").Formula = "=IF(AK4=0,0, T4)"
    Range("am4:am200").Formula = "=AJ4*AK4*0.01"
    Range("at4:at200").Formula = "=(AP4-AQ4)*33.34%"
    Range("au4:au200").Formula = "=AT4+AS4"
    Range("av4:av200").Formula = "=AP4-AQ4-AT4"
    Range("aw4:aw200").Formula = "=T4-V4+AP4-AQ4-AS4-AT4"
End Sub
```

Many thanks

Comment: You could sort your data by column u and then apply only to those rows greter than 1, or loop through each row and check the value of U.

Comment: Not exactly what you are asking for, but maybe you could add the test in your formulas like `=IF(U4>1,T4*U4*0.01,"")`

Comment: @h2so4 - yes, much more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For i = 4 To 200
If Range("u" & i).Value > 1 Then

Range("v" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*RC[-2]*0.01"
Range("x" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]-RC[-2]"
Range("aj" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[1]=0,0, RC[-16])"
Range("am" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]*RC[-2]*0.01"
Range("at" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-4]-RC[-3])*33.34%"
Range("au" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]+RC[-2]"
Range("av" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]-RC[-5]-RC[-2]"
Range("aw" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-29]-RC[-27]+RC[-7]-RC[-6]-RC[-4]-RC[-3]"
Else
End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub tommountain()
Dim rng As Range, cell_search As Range
Set rng = Intersect(Range("U:U"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
For Each cell_search In rng
If (cell_search.Value) > 1 Then
    'If the cell in range u:u is larger than 1, we execute the following
    'Use cell_search.Offset to find the cells in which you want your formulas
End If
Next cell_search
On Error Resume Next
End Sub
```

You use cell.Offset(Rows, Col) to find a given cell using the position of the cell in question.

E.g. If we have that cell_search is equal to A1, cell_search.Offset(,1) would give us B1.

E.g. If we have that cell_search is equal to B2, cell_search.Offset(-1,-1) would give us A1.

If cell_search had reached A1, you would be using:

```
cell_search.Offset(1,1).Formula="SomethingSomethingSomething"
```

To past a given formula into (A+1,1+1)=(B,2)=B2.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I'm not familiar with search.offset, how would I use that?